# Xcode Preview Resume Button Shortcut

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, preview, swiftui

Is there a keyboard-shortcut to click the resume button in the canvas on Xcode Previews, instead of clicking it every time?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

<kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> is what you're looking for.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 14):

#### Quick Answer

> Editor -> Previews -> Refresh

#### Refresh canvas shortcut

<kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

#### Open canvas shortcut

<kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>↩ return</kbd>

---

## Automated way to refresh the preview

**Note that** there is an option called **Automatically Refresh Canvas** that is enabled by default and helps you to not refreshing it manually again and again.

---

## How to find ANY macOS apps shortcuts

In almost all macOS apps, you can use `help` menu to find the submenu item you want (some kind of preview in this case). And it will show you the exact location of the submenu alongside the associated shortcut:

[image: Preview]

I have searched for `preview` for this case :)

Comment: I have never used that search functionality under the Help menu item. It turned out be pretty useful :) Thank you for sharing this trick!

Answer (score 1):

### Xcode 15.2

In the latest version of Xcode, you can do this under Editor > Canvas > Refresh Canvas (or option + command + p).

[image]